# How to download file using url stored inside firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored the url of the pdf file stored in firebase storage, in database inside the node Pdf. I am trying to download the file from firebase storage with the help of the url stored inside the database.

```
public class DownloadFile extends AppCompatActivity{ 
DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
String root_child="my book"; 
@Override 
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
databaseReference.child("Pdf").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
@Override 
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(root_child)) 
{ 

String url=dataSnapshot.child(root_child).getValue().toString(); 
StorageReference island=storageRef.child("books").child(root_child).child(url); 
island.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() { 
@Override 
public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { 
pdfView.fromFile(file).load(); 
} 
}); 
}

}
```

The problem is nothing really shows up inside the `pdf` view. When I debug the app I found that `StorageReference island=storageRef.child("books").child(root_child).child(url);` is not creating the right reference. In short the file is not downloading. Since the file name varies according to what users upload, it is not possible for me to specify the file name hence I used `'child(url)'` so that it can search the file using the `url` but I am not sure if that is the right way to search a file.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post properly idented code for easy reading.

Comment: did you refer this https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of the problem myself.
I used `StorageReference island=storage.getReferenceFromUrl(url);` instead of `StorageReference island=storageRef.child("books").child(root_child).child(url);` . This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered while debugging, the file is not downloading because the reference is not correct.

How are you getting info from the user about which file to download ?

I believe you must be showing him the list of files which he/she has uploaded. So in that list you can store the info about the file_name. Now when the user clicks on the list-item, you can have the correct reference since you know the file_name from the clicked list-item.

Comment: The user first uploads the file from its phone and then the uploaded file should be displayed inside the pdf view. The file gets uploaded inside the firebase storage and the url is stored inside the database  but i am not able to download it using the same url..

Comment: How will you decide which file to download ? Are you displaying all the list of files that are uploaded in the listview so that when the user clicks on one of the item, it will be downloaded ?

Answer (score 0):

In the same matter i give you a different approach that i use when i was getting that same error.
actually i save file in `Firebase Storage` with the name of post_id to which the file is related and then give shot to the following code
give a look

```
                    private void downloadFile(final String postKey) {
                    File cFile = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), "app Directory");
                    final File cLocalFile = new File(cFile, postKey);
                    if (!rootPath.exists()) {
                        rootPath.mkdirs();
                    }
                    if (!cFile.exists()) {
                        cFile.mkdirs();
                    }
                    final FileDownloadTask downloadingTask = mStorage.child(postKey).getFile(cLocalFile);
                    downloadingTaskProgress(downloadingTask, cLocalFile);
                }

                private void downloadingTaskProgress(FileDownloadTask downloadingTask, final File cLocalFile) {
                    downloadingTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(final FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progressSize = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())
                                    / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File download complete: " + model.fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            try {
                                writeToStorage(cLocalFile);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "local file not created: " +
                                    exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                private void writeToStorage(File src) throws IOException {
                    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
                    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(localFile).getChannel();
                    try {
                        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
                    } finally {
                        if (inChannel != null)
                            inChannel.close();
                        if (outChannel != null)
                            outChannel.close();
                    }
                }
```

give some modification as per your need and this approach could work as it is in mine....

Comment: thnx for your suggestion. I will try this out.